# Prove that the dimension of $V$ is even and that $L^{(\dim V)/2}=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of finte dimension and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation such that $L=T^2+aT+bI$ is nilpotent, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a^2<4b$. Prove that $\dim V$ is even and  $L^{(\dim V)/2}=0$.

Some ideas?.

Comment: Hint for $n$ is even: the distinct eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of $X^2+aX+b$, so they're complex conjugate and thus they have the same algebraic multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^2+ax+b$ has only complex roots, as does $(x^2+ax +b)^n$. Noting that the minimal polynomial (a *real* polynomial) of $T$ divides this polynomial for some $n$, conclude that $T$ has only complex eigenvalues. So, the space $V$ must have even dimension.

Now, note that the largest a generalized eigenspace can be is of size $\dim V/2$

Comment: Your answer is very good, but as I prove that $L^{(\dim V)/2}=0$.

Comment: To do that, use the size of the generalized eigenspace